# SwiftUI changing the color of clear part inside of SF Symbol

Tags: swift, image, swiftui, sf-symbols

I am trying to change the color of clear(transparent) part inside of a `SF Symbol` called `delete.left.fill`. So far I've tried is as follows

```
Button(action: { return }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "delete.left.fill")
                            .background(Color.black)
                            //.accentColor(.black)
                            .font(.system(size: self.fontSize*0.75))
                    })
                        .frame(width: self.width, height: self.width)
                        .foregroundColor(.lightGray)
                        //.background(Color.black)
```

When I run the code as above, the result is like

[image: symbol].

At first, the `x`inside of the symbol was the same color as background. I want it to make black.

1. I tried to set the `backgroundColor` of the `Button` and it made
   whole `Button` black.
2. I tried to set `accentColor` of the `Image` to
   black. Nothing changed.
3. I tried to set `backgroundColor` of the
   `Image` to black. The result can be seen in the image.

The question is, is there a way to make just that `x`, inside the `symbol`, black programmatically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could mask the background and apply a custom style:

```
struct MyButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
  public func makeBody(configuration: MyButtonStyle.Configuration) -> some View {
    configuration.label
      .compositingGroup()
      .opacity(configuration.isPressed ? 0.5 : 1.0)
  }
}

Button(action: {}) {
  Image(systemName: "delete.left.fill")
    .foregroundColor(.green)
    .background(
      Color.black.mask(Circle())
    )
}.buttonStyle(MyButtonStyle())
```

The circle may not fit to any usage, but for this image it works okay:

[image]

Comment: one more question though, it works but when I tap the button effect is working but there is a gray circle behind it and black parts fades to white more than it should do. Any suggestions on that?

Comment: Yeah. that's ugly. Sorry for missing out. I update my answer. Now the button should behave nicely when tapped

Comment: and the oscar goes to you. yet, how does this `compositonGroup()` works?

Comment: @Faruk It treats subviews/modifiers as one before applying the modifier. in this case the views of `label` (= image, foreground, background and color)

Comment: Altogether prolly still not the best solution. A better way could be to re-render the image filling all internally clear-color masked pixels with the color you want. But I didn't have the time to get into that.

Comment: Well that is enough for me now. If you have the chance for update, it would be appreciated. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6):

as of **`iOS 15`** you can simply achieve that with `.foregroundStyle(.red, .blue)`

Answer (score 3):

As he warned with the circle, @Faruk's solution didn't work for me with the exclamationmark.triangle.fill

I created a ZStack with the fill and unfill versions to create a yellow triangle with a black exclamation point and a black border:

```
ZStack{
  Image(systemName: "exclamationmark.triangle")
    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
    .scaleEffect(1.1)
  Image(systemName: "exclamationmark.triangle.fill")
    .foregroundColor(Color.yellow)
}
```

I've only tried on couple of simulators, but it looks nice on iPadPro and iPad Mini